# Regex For Get Last URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have:

```
stackoverflow.com/.../link/Eee_666/9_uUU/66_99U
```

What regex for `/Eee_666/9_uUU/66_99U`?

`Eee_666`, `9_uUU`, and `66_99U` is a random value

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
$link = "stackoverflow.com/.../link/Eee_666/9_uUU/66_99U";
$regex = '~link/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)~';
# captures anything that is not a / in three different groups
preg_match_all($regex, $link, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Be aware though that it eats up **any** character expect the `/` (including newlines), so you either want to exclude other characters as well or feed the engine only strings with your format.
See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jC8mZ4/1).

Comment: This will capture any link with `link` word and not only for `stackoverflow`

Comment: @vks: True, but I guess there is a repeating pattern just before the three groups to capture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\K` here to makei more thorough.

```
stackoverflow\.com/.*?/link/\K([^/\s]+)/([^/\s]+)/([^/\s]+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jC8mZ4/2

Answer (score 0):

In the case you don't how the length of the String:

`$string = stackoverflow.com/.../link/Eee_666/9_uUU/66_99U`

`$regexp = ([^\/]+$)`

result:
`group1 = 66_99U`

be careful it may also capture the end line caracter

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of requirement, it's simpler to use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) combined with [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$url = 'stackoverflow.com/.../link/Eee_666/9_uUU/66_99U';
$elem = array_slice(preg_split('~/~', $url), -3);
print_r($elem);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Eee_666
    [1] => 9_uUU
    [2] => 66_99U
)
```